# Swift - UITableView in UIScrollView content inset incorrect with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my `UIViewController` I have a `UIScrollView` and then a `UITableView` inside of that. I'm getting odd behaviour even without the `UIScrollView`. When my `ViewController` is not subclassed my `UITableView` (on its own) acts fine. I subclass the `VC` and all of a sudden the `TV` scrolls underneath my `navBar`. There's nothing that I've done in particular that I can see would cause this change, but since I'm working with AutoLayout for the first time in all these years, it may be something there which I'm overlooking. Anyway, I then fixed this manually with this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();

    var currentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = tableView.contentInset;
    println("Inset from top", self.topLayoutGuide.length)
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.topLayoutGuide.length, left: currentInsets.bottom, bottom: currentInsets.left, right: currentInsets.right);
}
```

Everything works again as expected (Even though I shouldn't have to do this). I then add in the `SV` into the mix and things go a little haywire again. The screen loads with the `TV` at `y= -64` which coincidentally (definitely not a coincidence) what it's `Inset` is set to. On touching anywhere, it snaps to `y= 0` (where it should always snap to and start at) and then with a little scrolling it'll go and snap to `y= +49`. The `TV` seems to have 3 snap points as mentioned above, yet I'm not sure why. The `SV` is set to have a scroll direction lock and paging enabled. It's `contentOffset` is the `screen height` (which is why I don't understand why it would cause these problems) x 2*`screen width`. If I remove my manual fix for the `inset`, as expected the issue is just shifted up by 64. Only, the `TV` reports the same heights of 0 & -64 (can't make it snap to +49) which is understandable as it shouldn't count the inset toward it's y scroll value in the scroll delegate.

Anyway, So I have absolutely no idea why my `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView` is playing up to the extent it is. I was always under the impression that a `UIScrollView` would automagically handle any content insets of it's direct child elements including `TableViews`.

If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Regards,
Mike

**UPDATE**: The issue, I have since found, lies with the way I'm setting my `contentOffset` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` I'm currently doing it like this: `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2 , self.view.frame.height);`. Still not sure why this line of code alone would cause the myriad of problems I've experienced.

Comment: You should cancel auto layout for insets working.

Comment: @Anton Just disabled Autolayout, but the issue still arises when the line of code I mentioned in the update is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using UIPageViewController instead to achieve the functionality I wanted, far better than using a UIScrollView.